# Java charAt() returning random integers instead of letters

Tags: java, charat

On CodingBat Java Warmup-1 on the "front22" problem, it asks me to return a string with the first 2 letters added to the front and back like this.

```
front22("kitten") → "kikittenki"
```

This is my code below and for some reason, the first two charAt returns numbers instead of the first two characters.

```
public String front22(String str) {
    return (str.length() > 1)
        ? str.charAt(0) + str.charAt(1) + str + str.charAt(0) + str.charAt(1)
        :  str + str + str; 
}
```

This returns:

```
front22("kitten") → "212kittenki"           
front22("Ha") → "169HaHa"        
front22("abc") → "195abcab"
```

Why does the last two charAt() work but the first two give these whacky numbers?

Comment: Because `char` is a *numeric* type, and since an expression is evaluated from left to right, the first two operands are numbers, and are added arithmetically. The third operand is a `String`, and causes all subsequent operands to be concatenated.

Answer (score 2):

Because `char` is a 16-bit integral type. The first few `char`(s) are added as integers (until you hit a `String` term, then it becomes `String` concatenation). Basically `+` has multiple meanings. Use a `""` as the first term to force the evaluation to be `String`(s). Like,

```
return (str.length() > 1)
    ? "" + str.charAt(0) + str.charAt(1) + str + str.charAt(0) + str.charAt(1)
    :  str + str + str;
```

**or** just make the first term a `String` any other way. Like,

```
return (str.length() > 1)
    ? String.valueOf(str.charAt(0)) + str.charAt(1) + str + str.charAt(0) + str.charAt(1)
    :  str + str + str;
```

Answer (score 1):

this is the expected result, chars are numbers... like integers
and you can verify its numeric value when look at the ascii table

[image]

so when you do `front22("kitten")`

```
str.charAt(0) + str.charAt(1)
```

you are adding numbers

in your case k+i in the ascii table:

> 107+105 = 212